# What is the correct way to include a pre-compiled library in meson-build?

Tags: dependencies, meson-build

I have a simple pre-compiled static library (from a hardware vendor -- hence no source) included in my sources and needing to be linked into my build. I had hoped it would be as simple as:

```
lib_foo = files('lib_foo.a')
...
foobar = static_library(..., link_with: lib_foo)
```

But I get an error saying that foo is not a target. I've tried dozens of variations of things to try to successfully link, and the closest I've gotten is this (using meson v0.55.1)

```
cc = meson.get_compiler('c')
abs_src_dir = meson.source_root()
cur_src_dir = meson.current_source_dir()
src_here_dir = abs_src_dir / cur_src_dir

warning('Searching: '+src_here_dir)
dep_foo = cc.find_library('lib_foo.a', dirs:src_here_dir, required: true)
...
foobar = static_library(..., dependencies: dep_foo)
```

And although I cannot get this exact example to work, I've gotten it to work in my build. However, even though src_here_dir is the exact path to the library in question (as proved by my warning), it often fails with a 'not found' error. Even when I can get it work, if I then try to build an RPM then it dies with a 'not found' although, again, its looking in the correct place.

I've yet to figure out why it sometimes finds the file and sometimes doesn't. In any case it appears to be a dead-end. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do this with a declare dependency, usually in a subproject, but you want to use `find_library`

```
cc = meson.get_compiler('c')

dep = declare_dependency(
  dependencies : cc.find_library('foo', dirs : [meson.current_source_dir()]),
  include_directories : include_directories('.'),
)
```

This is basically the same thing that's [documented here](https://mesonbuild.com/Shipping-prebuilt-binaries-as-wraps.html), but without the wrap. It is generally considered good style to put external library wrappers like this in a subproject when using Meson.

Comment: Thanks! This is much better than my solution!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Its not optimal, but it seems to work well:

```
abs_foo_dir = meson.source_root()
rel_foo_dir = meson.current_source_dir()

path_foo = abs_foo_dir / rel_foo_dir / 'lib_foo.a'

dep_foo = declare_dependency(link_args: path_foo)
...
foobar = static_library(..., dependencies: dep_foo)
```

This just injects the absolute library path as a linker flag, and that works, but feels kludgy. I'd prefer something more along the lines of:

```
cc = meson.get_compiler('c')
dep_foo = cc.declare_static_library('lib_foo.a')
```

But this will do for now.